# Java - replaceAll by regex, then replace first occurance of string

Tags: java, regex, replace

I have this string with HTML inside: `<span title="whatever">something I want to preserve</span>...`

I'm using a regex to replace `<span title="whatever">` with `(` and then the following `</span>` replace with `)`

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("<span\\s+[^>]*title=(['\"])(.*?)\\1[^>]*>");
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(strLine);
if (matcher.find()) {
    strLine = matcher.replaceAll("(");
    strLine = strLine.replace("</span>", ")");
}
```

I works but it replaces all `</span>` tags; I only want to replace the one that matches the opening tag I just matched.

Comment: Have you tried `replace` instead of `replaceAll` ?

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you need to replace any span with a title with (), but any span that does not have a title you want to leave alone. And the problem that you have above is that the opening tags `<span>` are being replaced correctly, but too many of the closing tags `</span>` are being replaced (ie. the ones matching opening tags without title. Is this correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not do it in one `replaceAll(...)` call:

```
String s = "noise <span title=\"whatever\">something I want to preserve</span>...";
s = s.replaceAll("<span\\s+[^>]*title=(['\"])(.*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*?)</span>", "($3)");
System.out.println(s);
```

which will print:

```
noise (something I want to preserve)...
```

#### EDIT

Note Alan's comment under my answer: this assumes you don't have nested `<span>`'s in your input.

Comment: This assumes there won't be any other `<span>` elements nested inside the one you're matching.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use a single regex for matching the entire `<span ...>...</span>`. Capture the `<span>` in one group and the `</span>` in another and use the capture groups to do the replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of replacing the `<span>` tags, you could try to extract the content of the `<span>` tag and then wrap it with braces.